# Android java.lang.NullPointerException with OnClickListener

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I keep getting this java.lang.NullPointerException on the line where mLoginButton's onClickListener is initiated.

I don't know what is wrong and have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but it doesn't work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Button mLoginButton;
private Button mNewAccountButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mNewAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newaccount_button);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
}

private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {
    mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showToast(getString(R.string.login_message));
            finish();
        }
    });
    mNewAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showToast(getString(R.string.newacount_message));
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void showToast(String toastString) {
    //do something       
}
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Which line inside the `onClickListener` initialization is it happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to `findViewById` before you `setContentView`. You must set the content view before you reference any view objects.